# Why are there no timeout errors in Next.js server actions?

Tags: next.js, vercel, server-action, timeouterror

I am building a Next.js application that downloads a file into the server and saves it into Firebase cloud storage. Initially I made an API that will do all this stuff, which worked when in development but gave a timeout error when deployed to the vercel and ran in production.

But as I modified the code into a server action, there were no timeout errors both in deployment and production. I even tried downloading very big files but still there were no timeouts. Not sure why this is happening. Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Any errors that you specified with `console.log()`, etc. should be in your vercel logs (https://vercel.com/docs/observability/runtime-logs). Are they not there either?